# Update item when file is created in folder which is created with FLOW

Tags: folder, library, flow, item, update

I've got a list A. 
When an item is created, a folder is created in library A.

When a file is created in one of the folders in Library A, the item (which triggered the folder) from List A must be updated.

Is that possible?

thanks in advance!

Comment: hey @marge.. as of today we have new action 'Create new folder' added....you can avoid using creation of dummy file and deleting it etc... hre is my post on same on how it works... http://siddharthvaghasia.com/2019/07/23/ms-flow-create-new-folder-action/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. What you need to do is create relation between library and list.

Create a column in Library A 'ItemIDOfListA'.

Create flow on List A - When item is created in List A, create folder in LibraryA and update column 'ItemIDOfListA' with item id.

Create flow on Library A -

- when a file is uploaded to library, get folder in which document is uploaded, get value of ItemIDOfListA column.
- Query List A using item Id and updated your list item as per your requirements.

Edit - Just tried MS Flow to update Library Column with Item Id of list item which triggered workflow. It is working fine.

Output

[image]

Design of MS Flow

[image]

Comment: Thank you Siddharth. I can't get it to work.

Comment: I used File Properties to update the column in LibraryA. The column doesn't get updated. I appreciate your time.

Comment: any error in file properties action ?

Comment: I tried, it is working...please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the graphics, that is helpfull. Myfolder is an excisting folder. To create the folder I have the Flow create a text file: /projectdocumenten/newfolder/empty.text. I know found out that the folder name is not: /projectdocumenten/newfolder but /projectdocumenten/newfolder/empty.text

Comment: so did it worked ?

Comment: no it didn't. see my previous comment. know=now

Comment: change the logic to create folder rather than creating text file.

Comment: but is isn't possible to create a folder with Flow, isn't it?

Comment: oh right, this is workaround you are using....then can you query based on folder name? you would generating this path in string right?

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround. Unfortunately the folder name contains the name of the created file. It should be /newfolder but it is: /newfolder/empty.txt. I don't understand. I need to get rid of the empty.txt extension

Comment: Have a look at this.  I responded to something similar about folders: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264922/sharepoint-online-button-to-create-a-new-folder-structure-in-a-document-library/264938?noredirect=1#comment281641_264938

Comment: hey @marge.. as of today we have new action 'Create new folder' added....you can avoid using creation of dummy file and deleting it etc... hre is my post on same on how it works... http://siddharthvaghasia.com/2019/07/23/ms-flow-create-new-folder-action/