# SharePoint Online button to create a new folder structure in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

I would like to add a button that appears on a SPO Modern Document Library that states "Create a new folder structure". (see below image).

[image]

When clicked I would like that button to:

1. Prompt the user to enter a Name and hit OK.
2. Create a pre-defined folder structure of multiple sub-folders where the top-most folder is the name they entered in the above step.

E.g. the end outcome is a folder structure as below.

- "My Folder Name I entered"

  - Sub-Folder 1

    - Sub-Sub-Folder 1.1
    - Sub-Sub-Folder 1.2
  - Sub-Folder 2

    - Sub-Sub-Folder 2.1
  - Sub-Folder 3

I'm not quite sure where to even start...How might I go about achieving this from a no-code and code perspective..?

Could this be achieved with a combination of Flow + PowerApps?

OR

If I go down the path of SPFx, is there any good starting point examples that someone could point me to build from?

p.s: I'm aware of Document Sets and creating a Folder that is copy and pasted as solutions, however I'm more interested in something custom.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below is what you need to do.

- Create SPFx extension of type List View Command Set
- Location of Command set should be set to ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar
- Use OnExecute Method to prompt dialog which take inputs from user as folder name
- Use REST API to create Folder and subfolders as per your requirement

Below are reference links to get started

- Create your SPFx extension using this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)
- Use OnExecute method provided in this [sample](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api#enhance-the-listview-command-set-rendering)
- Using rest api to create folder follow this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Below is sample onExecute method to use

```
    @override
    public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
      switch (event.itemId) {
        case 'COMMAND_1':
          Dialog.alert(`Clicked ${strings.Command1}`);
          break;
        case 'COMMAND_2':
          Dialog.prompt(`Clicked ${strings.Command2}. Enter something to alert:`).then((value: string) => {
            Dialog.alert(value);
// USE REST API TO CREATE REQUIRED FOLDER STRUTURE, value VARIABLE WILL HAVE FOLDER NAME WHICH USER ENTERED.

          });
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error('Unknown command');
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with Flow and PowerApps (except no button in the actual library)

1) Create a PowerApps some thing like:
[image]

1.1) Trigger the Flow(You can disable the button after it is click and other validation as needed)
[image]

2) Create a folder with a txt file (which can be deleted after structure is created) and folder structure will be ensured by SharePoint
[image]

3) SharePoint Library - Folder Structure
[image]

Comment: A couple follow-up questions. 

(1) Will this work in my situation as I have multiple Folders and Sub-Folders, 5 Folders in total with each one have 2-10 Sub-Folders.  

(2) How can I trigger the PowerApps form ? it doesn't necessarily need to be a button from the Document Library, can be a Quick Link web part or something accessible from the Homepage of the Team Site.

Comment: Well I think this is what my Flow answer is doing, take the first name of the Folder and Create all sub-folders structure it doesn't matter how many sub folders.  You can just create the sub folder structure you want in the compose action. 2) Like I am doing, go to PowerApps and create Flow.  I will edit my answer a bit